# Child theme enqueuing with dependencies

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a child theme. The parent theme has a style.css and all, and I was looking at `wp_enqueue_style()` function, and it says that you can inlude dependencies. So that means that the themes own `style.css` can be active, and in my child theme if I specify the same rule in my style.css, it should overwrite it.

But the dependency is an array of handles. How do I find those handles?

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'mytheme-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css', array('main_css') );
```

I tried with the above, but it only loads the style.css from child theme, not the parent.

Where can I find these handles?

EDIT:

I found the code for reproducing the handles and scripts:

```
function wpa54064_inspect_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle ) :
        echo $handle,' ';
    endforeach;
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpa54064_inspect_scripts' );

function wpa54064_inspect_style() {
    global $wp_styles;
    foreach( $wp_styles->queue as $handle ) :
        echo $handle,' ';
    endforeach;
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpa54064_inspect_style' );
```

But it still doesn't work the way I thought it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` will return the child themes URL if active.

Since you're trying to load the style.css file inside your parent theme you can use `get_template_directory_uri()` instead.

E.g:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'mytheme-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('main_css') );
```

My suggestion would be to load your stylesheets like this (code goes inside your child theme's functions.php):

```
function wpse_load_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mytheme', get_stylesheet_uri(), array( 'parent-styles' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_load_styles' );
```

Comment: This works the way I want to! I just need to find out how to dequeue the  css from the plugin and I'm set :) Thank you ^^

Comment: So, what if I'm forced to build a child theme on a super terrible theme with tons of css files? How would one load the parent's main `style.css` and a bunch of `/css/dumb-plugin.css` files? - and why is it an array? / is that helpful in this instance? Thanks.

Comment: You wouldn't need to worry about the additional CSS files. The parent theme would be responsible for loading those. Often the parent theme will load `get_stylesheet_uri`. When you're using a child theme it will load that stylesheet instead of the style.css file in the parent theme. It will still load other CSS files as normal. The array in my answer is a list of dependencies. We're telling it to make sure those files are loaded before this one.

Comment: I guess there must be another problem then, because everything is looking pretty broken / but the JS seems to be be in order. Hmmm. Well Thanks for the response.